# Getting 400 Bad Request on axios post call

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm using a url shortner API to test connecting to a API and I keep getting a 400 BadRequest.  I've read through a dozen posts here and tried all suggestions and still nothing will work.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Function

```
var axios = require('axios');
```

module.exports = function (callback, data) {

```
let url = 'https://cleanuri.com/api/v1/shorten';

let axiosConfig = {
    "headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
};
  

let longUrl = { "url" : data };

axios(url, {
    method: "post",
    params: {
        "url" : data
    },
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
.then(function (response) {
    callback(null, response.data);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("error: " + err.response);
    callback(err, null);
});
```

---

I've also tried this and got same error

```
    axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(longUrl), axiosConfig)
.then(function (response) {
    callback(null, response.data);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("error: " + err.response);
    callback(err, null);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data as body use `data` field on request options

```
const payload = { ... }
axios({ ..., data: payload })
```

`params` field is used to send query string within url

I have read your api docs https://cleanuri.com/docs.
That requiring your payload send as body, so use `data` field

Here the snippet:

```
let payload = { "url" : data };

axios(url, {
    method: "post",
    data: payload,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
```

Edit:
400 Bad Request is indicating your request is invalid (by server)

Comment: I'm still getting a 400 bad request.  I've even put in "http://google.com" instead of data in the payload and still same issue.

Comment: See this https://runkit.com/ardyfeb/60a931e8325992001a737560

Comment: That worked but when I put data variable back in the payload I get badrequest error again.  I know it is a valid encoded URL because I see it in debugger.

Comment: @CodeMan03 No I never figured this out.